# using prefix sum - parallel or sequential

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I have been wondering about when to use Parallel prefix sum instead of using sequential buildup. The algorithm I am using constructs parallel sums but I read somewhere that for small number of elements (typically less than 100 elements), its better to go for sequential algorithm. This brings the question of whether there is a certain threshold above which parallel implementation might yield some gain over sequential? I am using opencl for coding and have implemented parallel prefix sum using Blelloch 1990 implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, as usual. On the implementation, the device, and the size of the data.

[GPU Gems 3, chapter 39](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) has some pretty graphs that show when *their* specific implementations have thresholds. They didn't implement the algorithm naively of course - it's an optimized version using shared memory, unrolled loops, and cache bank conflict-avoidance.

Once you have an implementation, you'll just have to benchmark it to find the threshold.

Comment: So from what I see, there should be atleast 10^4 elements, before the parallel implementation takes precedence over sequential implementation.  Well thank you for the answer.